# How to plot line graph with x and y categorical axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line graph that compares 2 categorical variables. However I keep running into errors. I've put my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ["bored", "happy", "bored", "bored", "happy", "bored"]
dog = ["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy", "bored", "bored"]
activity = ["combing", "drinking", "feeding", "napping", "playing", 
"washing"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(activity, dog, label="dog")
ax.plot(activity, cat, label="cat")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: How do you plot a line graph of categorical variables?

Comment: The code from the question produces [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2zTl.png) in matplotlib 2.1. If you use an earlier version you will not be able to plot strings. If you encounter errors you need to include the full errortraceback in the question.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I could do it without install version 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide an answer here: When being run with matplotlib >=2.1, the code from the question

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ["bored", "happy", "bored", "bored", "happy", "bored"]
dog = ["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy", "bored", "bored"]
activity = ["combing", "drinking", "feeding", "napping", "playing", 
"washing"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(activity, dog, label="dog")
ax.plot(activity, cat, label="cat")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

runs fine and produces

[image]

---

For earlier versions of matplotlib, axes should be numeric. Hence you need to convert the categories into numbers, plot them, then set the ticklabels accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ["bored", "happy", "bored", "bored", "happy", "bored"]
dog = ["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy", "bored", "bored"]
activity = ["combing", "drinking", "feeding", "napping", "playing", 
"washing"]

catu, cati = np.unique(cat, return_inverse=True)
dogu, dogi = np.unique(dog, return_inverse=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(len(dog)), dogi, label="dog")
ax.plot(range(len(cat)), cati, label="cat")

ax.set_xticks(range(len(activity)))
ax.set_xticklabels(activity)

ax.set_yticks(range(len(catu)))
ax.set_yticklabels(catu)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it. I will remember for future reference.